# ARC causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS with SocketRocket

Tags: objective-c, macos, websocket

I'm trying to get SocketRocket to work on OSX, but I've ran into many issues. I finally compiled the framework for OSX 10.6, but whenever I start my app with ARC enabled I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, address=0x0). Here's the asm which might mean nothing:

```
0x7fff96f4be83:  je     0x7fff96f4beb0            ; objc_msgSend + 48
0x7fff96f4be85:  testb  $1, %dil
0x7fff96f4be89:  jne    0x7fff96f4bec7            ; objc_msgSend + 71
0x7fff96f4be8c:  movq   (%rdi), %r11
0x7fff96f4be8f:  pushq  %rax
Error>>>0x7fff96f4be90:  movq   16(%r11), %r10
```

However, if I disable ARC in my app, the framework works fine, and connects.

---

Here's all of my code:

Header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h>

@interface WebSocket : NSObject <SRWebSocketDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) SRWebSocket* socket;

-(void)connect;

@end
```

Class

```
#import "WebSocket.h"

@implementation WebSocket

@synthesize socket = _socket;

-(void)connect
{
    _socket.delegate = nil;
    [_socket close];

    _socket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://echo.websocket.org"]]];
    _socket.delegate = self;

    [_socket open];
}

#pragma mark - SRWebSocketDelegate

- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket;
{
    NSLog(@"Websocket Connected");
}

- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
{
    NSLog(@":( Websocket Failed With Error %@", error);
    _socket = nil;
}

- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message;
{
    NSLog(@"Received \"%@\"", message);
}

@end
```

In App Delegate:

```
WebSocket* client = [[WebSocket alloc] init];
[client connect];
```

---

**Update**:
I guess that's what being tired does to you.
`WebSocket* client` was going out of context and being nullified with ARC on. Duh! Sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: Did you try using exception break point. http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: Turns out it was me being stupid, but thanks for that post!

Comment: What did it turn out to be? I have run into the same issue

Comment: Look at my update. The reference to the pointer was going out of context and being deallocated by arc. I needed to retain a pointer to the client.